# Type conversation of objects in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, function, types, type-conversion

How to write a function on python that accepts two objects in input and gives on output minimal type which both of objects can be presented?
For example, if we have `[1, 2, 3]` and `2` we can convert it to `str`, if we have `"Hi"` and `1.2` we can convert it to `str`, if we have `True` and `1.2` we can convert it to `float` and so on.

Comment: Can you please clarify what you mean by "if we have ```True``` and ```1.2```, we can convert it to ```float```"?  Do you mean you can convert ```True``` to a float?

Comment: This looks like an x y problem. What are you trying to solve with it?

Comment: @ewong Yes. And it's minimum possible type to convesation. For example, we can convert them to ```str```, but ```float``` is less than ```str```, that's why the answer is ```float```

Comment: @KlausD. I tried to write some inequalities like type(int) < type(float) < .... < type(str), but that's not correct

Comment: Why should one type be less than the other?

Comment: @KlausD. to convert them to the common type. For example,  we have objects with types  ```str```, ```int```, ```float```, ```list```, then ```str``` is the minimum possible type that all the objects can be converted to, because we can not convert them all to ```int```, ```list``` and so on

Comment: You have not answered both of my questions. In the end it keeps completely unclear what you are trying to archive with your type conversion. It does not looks like you are going into the right direction.

Comment: @KlausD. Example: we have two objects: ```1``` and ```5.25```. We can't convert them both to ```int``` because then we will miss information about ```5.25``` that will be converted to ```5```. We can convert them both to ```float```: ```1.0```, ```5.25``` and it's correct. Of course we can say that we can convert them both to ```str```: ```"1"```, ```"5.25"``` but in our interpretation we think that ```int < float < tuple < list < str```(just abstraction) and then ```float``` is the minimum available type that both objects can be converted to.

Comment: To be more clear: I don't want another example of your strange approach. I want to know the original use-case. Type conversion is no use-case.

Comment: @KlausD. You mean why  I need this function?

Comment: Maybe someone know how to fix it?

Answer (score 1):

All objects in Python can be converted to strings, even user defined class instances.

```
>>> class Test:
    pass

>>> t = Test()
>>> str(t)
'<__main__.Test object at 0x0000015315891730>'
>>> str(1)
'1'
>>> str(True)
'True'
>>> str([1, 2, 3])
'[1, 2, 3]'
>>>
```

This is because they have a `__str__` function that is automatically defined even if you don't define it.

Edit: You can do it like this (pardon the ugly code)

```
def leastConversions(first, second):
    type_casts = [str, int, float, tuple, list, dict]
    times = {}
    for _type in type_casts:

        if not isinstance(first, _type):
            times[_type] = 0
            try:
                if not isinstance(first, _type):
                    temp = _type(first)
                    times[_type] += 1
            except TypeError:
                del times[_type]
                continue
            
            try:
                if not isinstance(second, _type):
                    temp = _type(second)
                    times[_type] += 1
            except TypeError:
                del times[_type]
                continue
    return min(times, key = lambda k: times[k])
```

Comment: It is obvious that we can convert it all to ```str```, but the question: what is the minimum type, that both of objects can be converted to? For example, the answer for ```True``` and ```1.2``` is ```float```, the answer for ```[1, 2]``` and ```(1, 2)``` is ```list``` and so on

Comment: The answer for `True` and `1.2` is also `str`, unless you're looking for the least number of conversions you need?

Comment: I edited my answer, perhaps this is what you're asking for.

Comment: But it has a problem. I tried to make the same thing with ```isinstance``` but when you compare ```int``` and ```float``` it convert it to ```int```, not to ```float```. My atteempt is lower

Answer (score 0):

When compare `int` and `float` answer is `int` but should be `float`

```
def type_convertion(first, second):
    data_types = [int, float, tuple, list, str]
    times = {}
    for _type in data_types:
        times[_type] = 0
        try:
            if isinstance(_type(first), _type):
                times[_type] += 1
        except TypeError:
            del times[_type]
            continue
        try:
            if isinstance(_type(second), _type):
                times[_type] += 1
        except TypeError:
            del times[_type]
            continue
        return times.keys()
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).